# How to rename directory using SmbUtils?

Tags: java, file, directory, smb

I am trying to rename a folder created with `SmbUtils`, but I don't find a method for that.

So I tried to create a new folder, with the name I want, and then copy the content of the existing one to it, but it is not copying the intern folders of the parent folder I am copying.

So here are my questions:

1) Is it possible to rename a folder with SmbUtils? If yes how? If not:
2) How to copy a folder with SmbUtils, and its content (files and intern folders)

Here is the code I am using (..and is just copying the intern files, but not the intern folders) to copy the folder in my self-implemented SmbUtils:

```
public void copyFolder(SmbFile source, SmbFile destination) {
        try {
            if (source.exists() && source.isDirectory()) {
                if (!destination.exists()) 
                    destination.mkdirs();
                source.copyTo(destination);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and here is how I am calling that method in another class..

```
try {
            originalFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + originalPath.replace("\\", "/"), smb.getAuth());

            destinationFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + destinationPath.replace("\\", "/"), smb.getAuth());
            smb.copyFolder(originalFile, destinationFile);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: renaming and moving can be different things. From what to what you do try to rename?

Comment: There's numerous things around named SmbUtils , which particular one are you using ?

Comment: @zapl I would like to rename the existing folder, which contains already other folders and files in it. Creating another one with the name I need. copying the existing files in the source one, was just an alternative that didn't worked. So I want to "simply" rename a directory, from for ex,  "C:\test\test2\unknown_unkwon" to "C:\test\test2\abcd_1234"

Comment: @nos what do you mean? which things? for ex..? I want to rename a folder.

Comment: @ZeleIB Where did you get your "SmbUtils" class/library? I'm saying there's several libraries/classes named SmbUtils, none of them are part of standard Java. I'm wondering where you got yours from.

Comment: @nos I edited my question.. is it better or should I give you more infos?